# Testrail API Ruby add_result_for_case error

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber, testrail

I am executing the code below as a cucumber step. The test case id is
C70. I tried a run ID and it gave the same error.

```
The code and error are below - 
-----------------
require 'testrail-ruby'
client = TestRail::APIClient.new('https://xxxx.testrail.net')
client.user = 'xxxxxxxxxx.com'
client.password = 'xxxxxx'
r = client.send_post(
'add_result_for_case/C270',
{ :status_id => 1, :comment => 'This test worked fine!' }
)
puts r
```

The Error:

> TestRail API returned HTTP 400 ("Field :run_id is not a valid ID.")

What am I doing wrong? I have researched this topic and have not resolved it  Please advise....

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem . I should have used the full Test Case ID. The ID that found when running the actual test case . The issue is resloved.

Answer (score 0):

Extra suggestion.
Do not use characters other than numbers when giving the ID information. For example, when giving the case Id, it shows up as C270 in Testrail. But you have to give it as 270 in Api. In another example, let your RunId be R150. You only need to give it as 150.